# What do the blue colored areas mean on the map in Cataclysm?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I was thinking the area shown in blue colored in the map is the water area. But it looks like that is not the case. What does it mean?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This shows the area of where your items for your quest will be located.  It helps players get a sense of where to look for the required items.

For example, in your case, you may need to kill 10 grand tigers in STV.  Grand tigers will be located in the blue shaded area shown on your map.

Comment: exactly what he said, beat me to it, was busy editing the title and stuff

Comment: I guess that too, but why does it not appear to all but only to few quests? if it got enough clarity, it highlights the area ONLY if there is something we need to collect the drop by killing mobs or by opening boxes etc.,?

Comment: Post the quest title.  Some quests require for you to observe a location or listen to someone (NPC) who doesn't move at a specific point, or some quests require you to 'investigate' an area.  In these cases, there isn't a blue shaded area.

Comment: I haven't been to STV in a while, but behind the arena might be the panther killinq quest line?  Post the quest title and I can provide more assistance.

Comment: @GeoStrike Did this help at all?  If so let me know by +1 & or Check :)